# Linkedin Developer: [unauthorized]. IP Address Mismatch

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I tried to share a html page on linkedin using the Javascript API and the following format. I didn't need any image, so I left it blank.

```
{
  "comment": "Check out developer.linkedin.com!",
  "content": {
    "title": "LinkedIn Developers Resources",
    "description": "Leverage LinkedIn's APIs to maximize engagement",
    "submitted-url": "https://developer.linkedin.com"
  },
  "visibility": {
    "code": "anyone"
  }  
}
```

I get an error [unauthorized]. IP Address Mismatch from the API, when I change the "submitted-url" to my html page. The code works fine when I try to share a linkedin url, the one given in the example above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The share url should be a publicly accessible url.

My url was "local.mpr.com" which I had configured using my IIS. So, the question is, can't I test the linkedin api unless I share a url that is available in the public domain.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with LinkedIn API but the [unauthorized] error could be cause of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)